# User Role not showing in Users Screen

Tags: users, user-roles

I'm trying to find a hook to let the custom user role that i've created show in the filter options inside of users.php. I've looked everywhere for documentation on this.

[image]

Comment: Do you mean for the new role to show up as a new link in the same line as e.g. "Administrator (4)"?. What does your code look like?

Comment: Do you have any users assigned to the custom role? They should automatically appear here if you've properly set up the role.